# grouping a dictionary inside a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, grouping

I've just been studying python and I'm having trouble doing some exercises. I have a list containing, I think, a dictionary:

```
dictionary_title=[
{'Color': 'Green', 'ids': 878},
{'Color': 'Pink', 'ids': 16},
{'Color': 'Orange', 'ids': 28},
{'Color': 'Yellow', 'ids': 9648},
{'Color': 'Red', 'ids': 878},
{'Color': 'Brown', 'ids': 12},
{'Color': 'Black', 'ids': 28},
{'Color': 'White', 'ids': 14},
{'Color': 'Blue', 'ids': 28},
{'Color': 'Light Blue', 'ids': 10751},
{'Color': 'Magenta', 'ids': 28},
{'Color': 'Gray', 'ids': 28}]
```

now if i want to group by id, to have for example:

```
{878:['Green','Red'], 16:['Pink'], 28:['Orange','Black','Blue','Magenta','Gray'] and so on...}
```

Now this is my code:

```
dictionary={}
genres=[878,16,28,9648,12,14,10751]
for color in nodes:
  for index in range(0,len(genres)):   
        if genres[index] == color["ids"]:
            dictionary.setdefault(genres[index],[])
            dictionary[genres[index]].append(color["color"])
print(dictionary)
```

but my output is:

```
{878:['Green','Pink','Orange','Yellow','Red','Brown','Black','White','Blue','Light Blue','Magenta','Gray']}
```

How can i do?

Comment: What are `nodes` and `genres`? How do they relate to the `dictionary_title` list?

Comment: i have fixed my code. I'm sorry I'm very distracted

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: You still have `nodes`. Is that supposed to be `dictionary_title`?

Comment: I get the desired result when I run your code (after fixing `"color"` to `"Color"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need nested loops. Just loop over the list. If you only want to process the ids that are in `genres`, add a test for that, rather than another loop (if `genres` is long, convert it to a `set` for better performance).

```
for d in dictionary_title:
    if d['ids'] in genres:
        dictionary.setdefault(d['ids'], []).append(d['Color'])

print(dictionary)
```

Comment: I complicate my life too much. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use `defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

dictionary = defaultdict(list)
for d in dictionary_title:
    dictionary[d['ids']].append(d['Color'])
```